# ¿Cómo eliminar commits del historial que ya fueron subidos al origen?

Tags: git, git-commit

Hice varios cambios de prueba al “origen” (repositorio remoto) y ahora son solo basura, ¿Cómo los elimino? Estoy trabajando solo en este repositorio.

**EDIT**

Mi pregunta [sí está duplicada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/121), pero las respuestas no eran claras, así que agregué [una nueva respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/627/299)

Se puede cerrar esta pregunta.

Comment: No sé, aparentemente no. Esa respuesta no dice como borrar 10 ( o N ) commits del historial, aparentemente solo es para el último.

Comment: Ok retracto mi voto de cierre

Comment: Tienes razón Oscar cambio mi respuesta!.

Comment: Si estaba duplicada pero no era clara la respuesta. Voten para cerrarla

Comment: Pues ahora yo opino que no está duplicada y me parece mejor mantener esta también ya que como se menciona se refiere a N commits y no solo al último

Comment: @OscarRyz no encontré duplicidad de esta pregunta, me parece lógico mantenerla abierta y que califiques a la que apoyó a tu solución. Buen día.

Answer (score 8):

Lo primero que debes hacer es hacer un `reset` hasta el último commit válido que quieres mantener:

```
git reset <commit> --hard
```

donde `<commit>` es el *hash* del commit al cual quieres regresar.

Luego tienes que hacer un nuevo `push` con la opción `-f` para forzar la sobreescritura del historial

```
git push -f origin master
```

Answer (score 2):

La historia subida a un origen nunca debe ser borrada, creo que el camino correcto es usar

```
git revert 'commit'
```

Esto crea un nuevo commit en el cual se revierten los cambios hechos en el commit que hayas estipulado en el comando. 
Luego subes el comit al origen como harias con cualquier otro.

Comment: Esto genera mas commits basura que los cuales @OscarRyz desea deshacerse. Además una de las características de git es que justamente tiene la flexibilidad de reescribir la historia, lo cual se puede aprovechar aquí.

Comment: Si, pero git revert funciona en todos los casos, si los commits a borrar no son los ultimos en la historia este comando los revierte sin volver a ese estado del proyecto por completo, solo revierte ese commit. En esta pregunta no está especifico si los commit  que quiere borrar son los ultimos en la historia, aquello podría provocar problemas a personas buscando una solucion para commits más antiguos.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo correcto sería:

```
 $ git reset <commit> --hard
 $ git push -f origin master
```

[Aquí](http://christoph.ruegg.name/blog/git-howto-revert-a-commit-already-pushed-to-a-remote-reposit.html) puedes encontrar más información.

Comment: Hey Carlos veo que me ganaste con la respuesta! :(, en cuanto al mensaje yo lo cambio a "DELETED BY USER!" para que sea completamente eliminada por el moderador! :D

Comment: si me pareció muy extraño pero también supuse que lo ibas a editar rápido por eso no le dí ningún voto negativo ni reporte

Comment: Prefiero cambiarlo a "DELETED BY USER!" para que los usuarios no me den votos negativos cuando me encuentro en proceso de actualización de mi respuesta. =), por cierto en ocasiones no puedo editar rápido ya que estoy en el trabajo!!! jeje.