# Regresar un repositorio a un commit especifico

Tags: git

Basado en [¿Cómo puedo deshacer el último commit en Git?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/90/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-deshacer-el-%C3%BAltimo-commit-en-git).

¿Hay alguna forma de regresar un repositorio **Git** a un commit en espeficico?.

Por ejemplo:

- commit a "Primer commit"
- commit b
- commit c
- commit d
- commit e
- commit f
- commit g
- commit h "Versión actual"

¿Hay forma de regresar al "commit c"?.

Comment: Por regresar te refieres a descartar (eliminar) los commits del "d" al "h" o te refieres a obtener "c" en el working tree para solo revisarlo a crear otro branch a partir de el

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz En el working tree

Comment: Ok entonces la [respuesta de @Gepser](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/1459/20) es lo que necesitas

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4114095/1983854

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Sólo debes hacer `git checkout commitC` donde `commitC` es el hash de dicho commit.

Ejemplo:

Buscas en el log de git cuál es el commit al que quieres regresar:

`git log`

Tendrás algo como esto:

```
commit eb9b03c2e22305c965b610aa84a7d316e5cb208d
Author: oscar <oscar@oscar.(none)>
Date:   Thu Sep 19 16:05:51 2013 +0200

    commit3

commit 96046152e2515d651d777bac66602e4a50654f49
Author: oscar <oscar@oscar.(none)>
Date:   Thu Sep 19 00:13:37 2013 +0200

    commit2

commit 23abd7d49c00541fcac17acb1babd7a60a3e7c6e
Author: oscar <oscar@oscar.(none)>
Date:   Wed Sep 18 23:53:25 2013 +0200

    commit1
```

> Puedes ver más información sobre [git log acá.](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)

Luego haces esto:

`git checkout eb9b03c`

> Para más información sobre [git checkout puedes ver acá.](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)

Entonces tu `HEAD` estará apuntando hacia el `commit3`, siendo el resultado que necesitas.

Answer (score 17):

#### Solución

Basta con ejecutar el siguiente comando (remplazar `<hash>`):

```
$ git checkout <hash>
```

#### Explicación

Para poder realizar el salto de una confirmación (commit) a otra, debes conocer el número (hash) por el cual quedó registrado. Tomando en cuenta que el libro oficial de Git en español, sección [2.3 Fundamentos de Git - Viendo el histórico de confirmaciones](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1/Fundamentos-de-Git-Viendo-el-hist%C3%B3rico-de-confirmaciones), nos dice:

> Después de haber hecho varias confirmaciones, o si has clonado un repositorio que ya tenía un histórico de confirmaciones, probablemente quieras mirar atrás para ver qué modificaciones se han llevado a cabo. La herramienta más básica y potente para hacer esto es el comando `git log`.

Al ejecutar el comando `git log` sobre tu proyecto, tendrás algo parecido a esto:

```
$ git log
commit ca82a6dff817ec66f44342007202690a93763949
Author: Scott Chacon <schacon@gee-mail.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 17 21:52:11 2008 -0700

    Cambiado el número de versión

commit 085bb3bcb608e1e8451d4b2432f8ecbe6306e7e7
Author: Scott Chacon <schacon@gee-mail.com>
Date:   Sat Mar 15 16:40:33 2008 -0700

    Removido código de prueba innecesario

commit a11bef06a3f659402fe7563abf99ad00de2209e6
Author: Scott Chacon <schacon@gee-mail.com>
Date:   Sat Mar 15 10:31:28 2008 -0700

    Primera confirmación
```

El hash (o número de confirmación) será el conjunto alfanumérico que está seguido de la palabra **commit**. Copiarás dicho hash para utilizarlo con el comando `git checkout <hash>` que se encargará de mover el puntero **HEAD** de tu proyecto a la confirmación indicada. Ejemplo visual (tomando en cuenta que estás el proyecto está la rama `master`):

[image: Ejemplo de git checkout]

De esta forma podemos percibir que aunque tu puntero ahora apunta a una captura anterior, tus cambios posteriores a ella siguen existiendo.

Puedes obtener más información oficial y en español relacionado a este tema en la siguiente liga: [6.1 Las herramientas de Git - Selección de confirmaciones de cambios concretas](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1/Las-herramientas-de-Git-Selecci%C3%B3n-de-confirmaciones-de-cambios-concretas)

---

> **SHA corto**: Simplemente dándole los primeros caracteres del código SHA-1, Git es lo suficientemente inteligente como para figurarse cual es la confirmación de cambios (commit) deseada. Es necesario teclear por lo menos 4 caracteres y estos han de ser no ambiguos --es decir, debe existir un solo objeto en el repositorio cuyo código comience por dicho trozo inicial del SHA--.