# ¿Se pueden pasar cambios de una rama a otra en Git?

Tags: git, ramas-git

Empecé hace relativamente poco a usar Git y tengo la mala costumbre de empezar a programar sin antes crear una nueva rama. O sea, modifico el código directamente des de la rama `master`.

¿Se pueden mover los cambios realizados en una rama a otra y así dejar la rama `master` limpia?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sí, es posible.

#### Si aún no has hecho ningún `commit`

Ahora mismo estás en `master`. Si escribes `git status` verás una lista con los ficheros que han sido modificados pero no *commiteados*.

Simplemente crea la rama:

```
git checkout -b nueva_rama
```

Este comando la crea y automáticamente te lleva a ella, llevándose consigo todos esos cambios.
Efectivamente, si haces `git status` otra vez verás que esos cambios aparecen allí, por lo que al hacer un `commit` se incorporarán a esa rama `nueva_rama`, no a `master`.

#### Si ya has hecho algún `commit`

En este caso, primero habrá que deshacerlo. Tal y como se lee en [¿Cómo puedo deshacer el último commit en Git?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/94/83), usa:

```
git reset HEAD~1
```

o más veces si hay más commits. A partir de ese momento `git status` volverá a mostrar esos cambios en estado "no commiteado".

Entonces estamos otra vez en el punto anterior *Si aún no has hecho ningún `commit`*, así que sigue esos pasos.

Deberás tener también en cuenta que en `master` tendrás unos cuantos commits que deshacer. Por tanto, deberás volver al estado previo haciendo `git checkout <número del último commit válido>`.

Comment: entonce primero debo hacer git add . antes de crear cambiar ala nueva rama ?

Comment: @willianrojas no, al contrario: primero haz `git checkout <nueva_rama>` y luego `git add` ya desde la nueva rama.

Answer (score 4):

Si has tirado unos cuantos commits en master lo que tienes que hacer es simplemente crear la rama con `git checkout -b nueva_rama` como lo dicen las demas respuestas, si tienes algun cambio sin commitear lo `commit`eas o lo `stash`eas,  despues vuelves para tu rama `master` con `git checkout master`, buscan con `git log` cual es el commit al que la rama `master` debe estar, y cambias a master con `git reset --hard commit_hash`. Te deberia quedar tu nuevo branch con los commits que querias y tu rama master detras de esta sin los commits.

Si no has tirado ningun commits solo tienes que crear la rama y commitear tus cambios

Si la rama ya existia puedes hacer un `git rebase` https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase y despues pararte en master y hacer un `git reset --hard` como en el primer ejemplo