# Cómo vuelvo a lo que tenia en mi ultimo commit?

Tags: git

todavía no commitie, pero me equivoque y no se donde, por lo que no me funciona mi proyecto, como puedo hacer para que mis archivos vuelvan al estado de mi ultimo commit?

Comment: Hola. La pregunta no es de laravel es sobre una acción sobre un sistema de control de versiones. No has dicho cual es: ¿subversion? ¿git? ¿cvs? Entre más clara sea tu pregunta será mejor recibida y sera más probable que alguien que conozca del tema te ayude. Saludos

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo puedo deshacer el último commit en Git?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/90/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-deshacer-el-%c3%baltimo-commit-en-git)

Answer (score 1):

Para descartar los cambios del último 'commit' debes dar la siguiente instrucción:

```
    git reset HEAD~1
```

Puedes añadir '--soft' o '--hard' si quieres eliminar los archivos del todo o no del Index de git.

Sí lo que necesitas es mantener una versión anterior en lugar de 'reset' la instrucción debe ser 'revert', lo que creará un 'commit' con una versión anterior del repositorio:

```
     git revert HEAD~1
```

Sí necesitas que en lugar del último sean varios anteriores puedes cambiar '~1' el número de commits a borrar o eliminar, por ejemplo '~3'.

A continuación dejo un enlace a un página con documentación que puede resultarte de ayuda con tu problema: https://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/git-undo-commit/amp/

Answer (score 0):

para deshacer los cambios que aún no has comprometido tienes que usar:

```
git reset --hard
```

Con este comando vuelves al estado al que apunta el HEAD del repo, y dado que no has comprometido los cambios, los deshará. 
Te dejo el [enlace](https://support.beanstalkapp.com/article/1004-how-do-i-undo-things-in-git#1) que he seguido y el apartado concreto:

> ### How do I remove all uncommitted changes in my working directory?
>
> To undo all the changes you’ve introduced since the last commit, use the following command:
>   git reset --hard
>   This command reverts the repo to the state of the HEAD revision, which is the last committed version. Git discards all the changes you made since that point.

Comment: todavia no se sabe si es cvs o git