# Eliminar un commit en repositorio remoto

Tags: git, github, git-commit

En mi caso he intentado hacer:

```
git reset --hard 4c0aeb829bd89cc3251f2e0add605e7f11104e2f
```

desde vscode.

Es cierto que me elimina los commits que hice después de este, pero me gustaría saber como hacerlo también en el repositorio de github y que se borren allí también ya que solo me los borra de forma local y cuando intente hacer un push me sale que voy 5 commits por detrás de los del repositorio en GitHub.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo puedo deshacer el último commit en Git?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/90/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-deshacer-el-%c3%baltimo-commit-en-git)

Comment: Creo que la pregunta esta mal planteada, lo que intentas es reescribir la historia en el repositorio remoto, la publicación de @eftshift0 en resumen es correcta para responder la duda real del OP.

Comment: Recuerda que eso no te elimina un commit!!! Para nada que lo hace! Sino que pone el HEAD de tu rama en aquel commit. Eso significa que los commits posteriores a ese commit, serán un poco -mas no totalmente- inaccesibles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes que hacer un push -f para que quede en el remoto... asumiendo que ya tienes la rama upstream configurada, tienes que hacer

```
git push -f
```

Si no la tienes configurada:

```
git push -f <algun-remoto> <alguna-rama>
```

`<algun-remoto>` suele ser `origin` pero como no siempre es el caso.....